# how setting transaction parameter in core berkeletdb(dbapi) help in maintaining  database in database environment?

Tags: berkeley-db

We are using core Berkeley(dbbaseapi)and already processed Write/ReadCDRFile of 9 [lack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) records, now we are getting difference in performance while using transaction and without using transaction which are as follows:-

1. we Write/Read S-Max CDRFile implementing the concept of  Secondary Database:-

Using Secondary Database Concept (With Transaction):-

```
Operation   No.of Rows  Time 
Write CDRFile   9,66,320    5.8 minutes
Read CDRFile    9,66,320    1.36 minutes
```

Using Secondary Database Concept (Without Transaction):-

```
Operation   No.of Rows  Time 
Write CDRFile   966320          3.27 minutes
Read CDRFile    966320          1.28 minutes
```

we have already set parameter used in environConfig.setTransaction(true) and same in   database.

```
Transaction txn = databaseEnv.getDbEnv().beginTransaction(null, null);
```

and passed to here:-

```
databaseEnv.getCdrDb().put(txn, thekey, theData);
```

so reply that how transaction internally used on database and environment

Answer (score 0):

From subsequent questions that you've asked, it sounds like you've moved beyond this initial question. For the record, when configured for transactions BDB performs writes to the transaction log in order to provide recoverability in the event of an application or a system crash (automatic recovery is not available when BDB is used without transactions).

When using transactions, by default BDB will wait until the transaction has been written all the way to the disk (see the first two sections of [Getting started with Transactions](http://bit.ly/qOfnV5) to get more information about transaction durability and how to increase throughput by relaxing the durability constraints).

In addition to relaxing the durability constrains, as indicated above, you can also improve throughput by a) including multiple operations (inserts) in the same transaction rather than inserting a single record in a separate transaction, and b) by using the Bulk put API via the [putMultiple API call](http://bit.ly/nT6pJJ) (this will reduce the pre-call JNI overhead)

In the future, these questions may be more quickly answered on the Berkeley DB technical [forum](http://bit.ly/eIREhr) on OTN.

I hope that helps.

Regards,

Dave